# adding a pdf to a FancyBox gallery

Tags: jquery, fancybox

The documentation states "fancybox attempts to automatically detect the type of content based on the given url. If it cannot be detected, the type can also be set manually using data-type attribute (or type option)."  What value should I assign to data-type for a pdf?

If I add a pdf file with an explicit extension of .pdf to a gallery on a webpage, it opens in the fancybox gallery.  But when referenced on a phpBB board by, say, href="./download/file.php?id=15184", I get the error message "The requested content cannot be loaded.  Please try again later."

Answer (score 1):

pdf.js has issues on iOS displaying certain pdf files; the pages appear blank.  I posted the issue on github:  https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/11571

Someone suggested it has to do with canvas size; I don't know.  But heuristically, I have discovered that if I reprint any problematic pdf with CutePDF Writer, it generates a pdf that's palatable to pdf.js.  And pdf.js then renders html that's palatable to fancybox.  So now, the whole thing is wired!

Answer (score 0):

The default content type is `image` and there is no way the script can figure out what you want to do with `./download/file.php?id=15184`, it can be anything - image, html page, etc.

About pdf - you have to understand that pdf is a document format and, in order to display it inside webpage, it needs to be parsed. It can be done inside browser by some pdf library (https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) or by browser extension. In both cases you will need to display iframed page and that means that you have to add `data-type="iframe"` (or `data-type="pdf"` which is just a shortcut, it will generate iframe anyway) attribute to your links.

Comment: Hmmm... I admit to being confused. Here's a page which uses FancyBox to display a .jpg, a .pdf, a .mp4 and a .mp3 - all without iframes. The mp3 I was able to display because of the data-type="video" suggestion you made. I wondered if there was some similar attribute I could assign for pdf's. Oops - sorry, here's the link: 59plymouth.net/lightbox/fancybox.html

Comment: Well, if you would inspect HTML structure, you would find an iframe there.

Comment: I see - you are quite right:  <iframe id="fancybox-frame1570379761260" name="fancybox-frame1570379761260" class="fancybox-iframe" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" src="./media/ignition.pdf" scrolling="auto"></iframe>  But, the iframe is there, because FancyBox implicitly added it, not because I added it.  But the question remains - is there a way I can tell FancyBox that the object I wish to display in the gallery, is of type .pdf, when the phpBB reference does not explicitly identify it?  And hence, have FancyBox in phpBB display it, as this demo web page does?

Comment: Did you try adding `data-type="iframe"` or `data-type="pdf"` attributes to your links? Also, please, notice that pdf file URL in that demo page ends with `.pdf`, but your  link ends with indeterminable `file.php?id=15184`

Comment: ...oh, and by the way - I did try data-type="pdf" on a lark, but it did not work.

Comment: I will try data-type="iframe"

Comment: data-type="pdf" does not work - but, data-type="iframe" does!  Thanks for the hint, on to my next problem...

Comment: data-type="iframe" works - but, only on Windows.  On iOS, it doesn't.  Here's a sample webpage:  http://59plymouth.net/lightbox/fancybox.html - the same pdf is presented as a thumbnail, with and without Fancybox.  Without Fancybox, the pdf presents correctly as a two page document within iOS (either Safari, or Chrome).  With Fancybox, it only shows the first page, and there's excess whitespace.  I looked at the Request and Response headers with Fiddler, and they are identical.  The pdf.js script reads like stereo instructions to me - is there really no way to make Fancybox recognize as pdf?

Comment: fancybox can display any HTML code, but PDF .... is not HTML. You might as well ask fancybox to display Adobe Photoshop files or Microsoft Office documents. So, you have to use some PDF file parser like https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ to convert it to HTML.

Comment: All the built in functions of the native pdf viewer - scroll, zoom, pagination - are available in Windows, using FancyBox.  But not in iOS.  But they are in iOS, outside of Fancybox!  I'm doing the very basics now with pdf.js, but to reinvent the wheel (and, assuming I can do it within a Fancybox iframe) is just crazy.  I know that Fancybox just works on the DOM, but I'm not understanding why it can't exploit native MIME-type apps.  I guess I just give up.

Comment: Well, I tried to explain, but it looks like I failed. OK. Another try. You see, modern desktop browsers have built-in pdf viewing capability, for example, see this Firefox doc - https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/view-pdf-files-firefox Mobile browsers, however, do not have. As the workaround, you can use pdf.js to generate HTML code (like this https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) that can be embeded inside your page. It is really not hat hard, see examples https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/ Does that makes sense to you now?

Comment: Anyway, I just do not get it why it is so hard for you to understand that PDF is a document format, but browsers can understand HTML only. If you want to display your file in the webpage, there has to be some mechanism that reads it and converts to the code that browser understands, e.g., HTML. Some browsers have built in functionality to parse PDF files and generate HTML, some not. Funcybox just generates HTML code, it does not read/parse files, it is out of the scope of the project.

Comment: OK – I cobbled together a webpage using pdfjs with and without fancybox.  pdfjs works with Windows browsers in both examples – although, the fancybox example contains extensive blank space after the two pdf pages are rendered:  http://59plymouth.net/lightbox/fancybox.html

Comment: However, iOS has problems with pdfjs – with or without Fancybox.  It seems that scrolling the pdf rendered as html within an iframe is problematic.  This has been reported elsewhere:  https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/2

In that same thread, a remediation is outlined – and it says “It's much easier to control overflowed divs than it is iframes…  The auto-expanding iframe seems a likely culprit.”  Is there a way to implement this solution with Fancybox?

Comment: I've tried everything that has been suggested.  So, is there nothing to be done about iframe scrolling on iOS (of a pdf document rendered as html) within Fancybox?  Affecting iPhones, but iPad tablets as well?  There's simply no fix?

Comment: That answer says there is no solution to scrolling a pdf within an iframe under iOS.  The answer directly below that states "PDF.js can be the right choice", as you have been telling me.  However, there are still issues with scrolling - unless you wrap the html with divs, as cited in github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/2 with other attributes: overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; .  So again:  Is there a way to implement this solution with Fancybox?

Comment: I will repeat - "fancybox can display any HTML code", so, if you can, for example, successfully insert PDF file viewer on your page, there is absolutely nothing that would prevent you from displaying the same code inside fancybox.

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have access to an iOS device.  It's not Fancybox that prevents the display; it's iOS.  And it affects *any* long html page.  Others have proposed remediation by wrapping the html within the Fancybox iframe with the attributes I list above.  I'm laying this issue at the feet of iOS, not Fancybox.  But it affects 25% of the mobile device market.  Isn't there an interest in implementing this workaround, even though it's the fault of the OS?